# Call an anchor tag via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using thick box 3.1 to load a pop up. It working well by using in the following way:

```
<a href="filename.php" class="thickbox"> TEST </a>
```

If we click on the TEST now then the popup is working well and good.

Now my prob is: I need to call this popup in form load using JavaScript.

I do something like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.location.href = "filename.php"    

</script>
```

it's just redirecting to that particular file. But not showing in the pop up.

What is the possible way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="filename.php" class="thickbox" id="openOnLoad">Test</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ // On DOM ready
    $('#openOnLoad').click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks simeon, This is what i exactly wan't. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without changing your markup, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href=filename.php]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="filename.php" class="thickbox" id="UniqueIdForThisLink"> TEST </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#UniqueIdForThisLink").click();
</script>
```

Comment: @James: Yeah... true. My focus was on using `click()` as the answer to the question, not not on making a standalone fully functional example.